# Minus Front - Return Normal Shape Instead Of Compound Path or Group - Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, pathfinder

Sometimes, applying Minus Front on two shapes in Adobe Illustrator 2021 returns a normal single shape, other time, it returns a compound path. Why? Is it possible to force returning a normal path? Or is it possible to convert the Compound Path into Normal Shape after substruction ?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Please tell us which application you are using.

Comment: @Wolff Thanks, I've updated the question as per as your comment. I'm on Adobe Illustrator 2021 (v25.4.1 64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *Minus Front* operation results in a single closed path, it just returns a *single path*.

If it results in several unconnected paths, it returns a *group*.

If it results in a shape with a hole in it, it return a *compound path*.

If you hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the *Minus Front* button, you get a *compound shape* where the bottom path is "positive" and the top path is "negative" (subtracted).

If you afterwards click the *Expand* button and the result is several unconnected paths or a path with a hole in it, you get a *compound path* only consisting of positive paths. Otherwise you just get a *single path*.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit in doubt whether I covered all the quirks. Please let me know if you have some special case not covered here.

Comment: I added some more cases.

Comment: Thanks these informations are so useful. They explain very well how Minus Front works and why sometimes it returns a standard path while other time a compound one. I'm wondering if it's doable to merge "Unconnected Paths" into a single Standard Path (I'm producing SVGs for web).

Comment: A path is a collection of *connected* points. It's either open or closed. If two paths aren't touching they can't become one path. They can be held together as a compound path or as a group.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The blue shape is subtracted from the brown one in three cases. In the left the result is a group of 2 separate paths.

In the middle the result is a single path.

In the right the result is a compound path. It's the way how Illustrator presents paths which have holes.

**Not asked:** A path can be drawn with self cutting edge. It also can seem to have a hole, but it's a single path:

[image]

One can also combine 2 fully separate paths to a compound path by applying Object > Compound Path > Make

[image]

It's sometimes useful when the next operation needs a single path and doesn't work in a wanted way with a group. The most common such case is filling with a gradient:

[image]

In the left a group is filled with a gradient. In the right a compound path is filled with the same gradient.

Comment: Prefect explanation. Now everything's crystal clear. Thanks !

Comment: And yes I did it! I converted multiple paths into a single compound path thanks to the last point of your answer !